# Are there any wireless IPv6-ready home routers?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ipv6

Checked the router we have at home (D-Link DIR-655) and doesn't seem like it supports IPv6. Got curious; Are there any?

It would have to support bridging to IPv4 on the outside though, since the ISP is IPv4. Some bridging in-house would be nice too, since there are probably some devices that does not support IPv6 still.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The D-Link DIR-825 Supports IPv6

http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=681

You can read about it's support in the manual.

ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Gateway/dir825_revB/Manual/dir825_revB_manual_210.zip

It supports: DHCPv6, IPv6 over PPPoE, 6 to 4 Tunneling, and IPv6 in IPv4 Tunneling

Comment: No upvotes for a correct answer? =(

Answer (score 3):

The [**SixXS Wiki, Routers** page](http://www.sixxs.net/wiki/Routers) lists routers that support IPv6 out of the box.

The [**Six Access** site](http://www.sixxs.net/main/) in general is a good reference for **IPv6**.

> [**About SixXS**](http://www.sixxs.net/about/): not a company, but rather a privately conducted development of software.
>   As such, we do not have any owners except for the two Copyright holders, Pim and Jeroen, mentioned below, who set up SixXS with a lot of time and effort, building the service from the ground up as a community service.
>
> Our target is to provide decent IPv6 connectivity.
>   This thus involves the Tunnel Broker portion, but also monitoring the IPv6 routing tables using, amongst others, GRH.
>
> **For whom?** For everybody.
>   The average joe and jane can use AICCU so that they can use IPv6 very quick and easy.
>   For the technically savvy, they can also use AICCU or they can set the tunnel up manually, whatever one wishes.
>
> SixXS additionally provides services to the networking and internet operator community with tools like GRH which can be used for monitoring and debugging the IPv6 routing tables.

---

Some Microsoft notes on [**IPv6 Support in Home Routers**](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/network/IPv6_IGD.mspx) (March, 2005).

> Contrary to popular belief, Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6)-capable devices, computers, and routers can provide users with virtually all the benefits of IPv6 without having to wait for Internet service provider (ISP) support for native IPv6 connectivity. This is made possible through IPv6 transition technologies that support IPv6 communications over an Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4) network infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any that will do it off the shelf quite yet, but you can use an alternate firmware such as OpenWRT which has an [**IPv6 module**](http://oldwiki.openwrt.org/IPv6_howto.html).  The DIR-655 is not supported by OpenWRT, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I've seen is the wireless-only [Apple Airport Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/specs.html), though the number of ISP's that offer IPv6 can probably be counted on one badly mangled hand.

Also, the Cisco 870 series supports it but that leans more towards SOHO.